# Using Residual Plots to combat Simpson's Paradox and Other Misleading phenomenon

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, statsmodels

I've read that univariate analysis is a huge part of EDA, pretty much everywhere. What I understand of univariate analysis basically comes down to using Seaborn pairplot and correlation matrices and heatmaps.

However, today I read about ["Simpson's Paradox"](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Simpsons-paradox) on a kaggle kernel, then in a Britannica article. It was quite fascinating and seemed to render useless what I believed to be commonly accepted best practices.

I then read that one way to combat this sort of misleading analysis is through [partial residual plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot):

$$\text{Residuals} + \beta_iX_i \text{ vs } X_i$$

What I can't figure out is how this formula controls for multiple independent variables in an intuitive way. What's the explanation for how this works?

Comment: What is the reference that partial residual plots combat this?

Comment: @al0 This wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot, as well as the comments on this kaggle kernel: https://www.kaggle.com/pmarcelino/comprehensive-data-exploration-with-python